# Zend Framework baseURL error after deploying from os x to linux server

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have a Zend Framework application that works fine on my local OS X machine. The Zend folder is also included with my project in `library/`. When I set up my code on my Linux server I now get this error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Loader_PluginLoader_Exception' 
with message 'Plugin   by name 'BaseURL' was not found in the registry; used paths: 
Zend_View_Helper_: Zend/View/Helper/:/var/www/best_dashboard/application/views/helpers/'
in /var/www/best_dashboard/library/Zend/Loader/PluginLoader.php:412 Stack trace: #0 
/var/www/best_dashboard/library/Zend/View/Abstract.php(1182): Zend_Loader_PluginLoader-
>load('BaseURL') #1 /var/www/best_dashboard/library/Zend/View/Abstract.php(618): Zend_View_Abstract->_getPlugin('helper', 'baseURL') #2 
/var/www/best_dashboard/library/Zend/View/Abstract.php(344): Zend_View_Abstract-
>getHelper('baseURL') #3 [internal function]: Zend_View_Abstract->__call('baseURL', Array)
 #4 /var/www/best_dashboard/application/layouts/scripts/layout.phtml(11): Zend_View-
>baseURL() #5 /var/www/best_dashboard/library/Zend/View.php(108): 
include('/var/www/best_d...') #6 
/var/www/best_dashboard/library/Zend/View/Abstract.php(888): Zend_View-
>_run('/var/www/best_d...') #7 /var/www/best_dashboard/library/Zen in 
/var/www/best_dashboard/library/Zend/Controller/Plugin/Broker.php on line 336
```

Some of the other people I've seen with this error is because they are going from Windows to Linux and the case for BaseURL is different and brakes. I don't think this is my problem since I'm going from OS X to Linux.

What causes this error?

UPDATE:

I'm using Zend Framework 1.12.3

I'm using apache on the Linux server and MAMP on the local OS X machine.

Comment: How do you call the baseUrl() view helper ?

Comment: <?php echo $this->headLink()->prependStylesheet($this-  >baseURL().'/libs/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css'); ?>'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the right way to call the view helper is

```
$this->baseUrl()
```

(check the capitalization, Linux is a bit picky about that)

Comment: I changed it on Linux and it works now. I also changed it on my OS X machine and it is still working. Just confused why baseURL works on OS X isn't it just as picky as Linux?

Comment: Honestly, I don't know about OS X.  I had a similar problem with some file names on my Windows environment.  Since Windows is not case sensitive for the file system, including MyFile.php or myFile.php was the same but for Linux, MyFile.php and myFile.php are two different files.  When you call a function within a view in ZF, it will try to include the file which has the same name as the function but with a capital letter.  Meaning, when you call $this->baseUrl(), it looks for BaseUrl.php but when you call $this->baseURL(), it looks for BaseURL.php.  Hope this is clear ;)